# Enable/Disable button of a form from another class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

Hello my problem is: I am not able to enable a button of a form, from another class. My form class is

```
public class FileSending {
   //Function for enabling the button 
   public void activate_btnSEND (boolean flag) {
       SendFile.setEnabled(flag);      
   }    
}
```

And the class from where i am calling this function is as follows :

```
public class SMS {
   Public void split(){
      if(check_string.equalsIgnoreCase("0001"))  {                
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Recepient Has Accepted The" +
                                " Request.Connection Has Been Established :) ");  
           FileSending setBtn = new FileSending();
           setBtn.activate_btnSEND(true);               
      }
   }
}
```

I debugged the code to check the value that is being passed to flag and the value is *"True"*. It also goes inside the if condition but the Button is not enabled. I don't understand what is happening here !!

Comment: Is this a JButton? Are you trying to set to be visible, or set to be enabled? It's not clear.

Comment: @cheesysam Yes it is a Jbutton and i am trying to enable it.. as i have disabled it in the constructor

Answer (score 2):

Some points in your code:

1. First, you are enabling/disbaling, you making it visible if flag is true. You should use [`setEnabled(b)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setEnabled%28boolean%29),  So `SendFile.setVisible(true);` will become `SendFile.setEnabled(true);`
2. **Never** compare boolean like this `if(flag == true)`, it should be just `if(flag)`
3. And your methhod should be something like this:

   ```
   public void changeStateOfButton (boolean flag) {
   //now what ever you pass will decide whether to enable or disable the button.
     myButton.setEnabled(flag); 
   }
   ```
4. Or more better you should use [JToggleButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JToggleButton.html) for such things.
5. Also improve your variable naming skills.

---

A small example of what I'm saying:

```
public class TestButtonEnable {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("TestButtonEnable");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setSize(200, 200);
      frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      JButton button = new JButton("Enable that button");
      final MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();
      button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Some message. :)");
              panel.changeStateOfButton(true); // call second class method here
          }
      });
      frame.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

And second class containing jbutton:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    private JButton button;
    public MyPanel() {
        button = new JButton("Enable me");
        button.setEnabled(false); // disabled by default
        this.add(button);
    }
    public void changeStateOfButton (boolean flag) {
        button.setEnabled(flag); 
    }
}
```

Comment: did change my code both here and in my program but it isn't working :(
Plus the JToogleButton does not serve my purpose

Comment: @user1318860 Did you checked after clicking on `ok` button in MessageDialog?, cause as far as message dialog is on screen that method will not get called.

Comment: yes i did check that and i am doing almost the same thing but it isn't working any other way out ??

Comment: @user1318860 it's hard to tell by monitoring your that small piece of code. You might need to do some more debugging.

Answer (score 2):

check if you are not creating more then one object of FileSending class ....
you must not create more then one object of that class...
check if one object is created as part of your GUI class and another is as part of SMS class..

use only one object of FileSending class